# pass parameters when calling function in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am in the early stages exposed to Objective-c. I have a question is, with one function call like this, the parameters will be passed on like.

```
time_call = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
[Services get_time:self :@selector(callBackTime:)];
```

This is the function called

```
-(void) callBackTime:(NSString *)result 
{
    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
}
```

I don't understand result parameter passed to the function type as in the other what was called

---

I apologize for not stating explicitly question.
But here is the original function in Class Service

```
+(void) get_time:(id)delegate :(SEL)selector
{
    NSLog(@"get time call"); 
}
```

Comment: Here `[Services get_time:self :@selector(callBackTime:)];` you are calling the get_time method. Show the code written inside the get_time method.

Comment: are you the one who created Services?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I know that the function callBackTime is called. But I don't understand result parameter passed to the function type as in the other what was called

Comment: what is Service? className or object ?

Comment: Service it's class name

Comment: ...about the naming conventions in Objective-C: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you are not understanding, I suspect English is not your first language - which is OK! Here is a guess in the hope it helps.

Your original `get_time::` method in `Services` does not use its arguments, and as such will never call `callBackTime:`, so maybe this is why you say you "don't understand result parameter" - without a call no value is obviously passed for this parameter.

Consider this alternate definition of `get_time::`

```
+(void) get_time:(id)delegate :(SEL)selector
{
    [delegate performSelector:selector withObject:[NSDate date]]; 
}
```

Now the method uses its two parameters to invoke the passed method (`selector`) on the passed object (`delegate`) - the method requires one parameter and this is supplied (`[NSDate date]` - the current date & time, picked as your method is called `get_time`).

If you run this your `callBackTime:` method should `NSLog()` the current date.

Hopefully that helps you understand where `result` comes from - `get_time` needs to supply it.

HTH

**Addendum**

I missed that `callBackTime:` is declared to accept an `NSString *` and my example passes an `NSDate *`. The code will work due to Objective-C's lose typing, but to be correct either `callBackTime:` should take an `id` or my sample should pass an `NSString`, e.g. `[[NSDate date] description]` would do.

Comment: sorry for my question was not clear.
My english is not good, but google translate does not seem very efficient.
I mean, I do not understand when callBackTime function is called, then the parameters passed to its NSString what type. I do not see it being passed on.

Comment: In your original code the `callBackTime:` *method* was never called, the selector for the method was passed to `get_time::` - passing a selector does not call the method. In my example the method is called and passed a value for its `result` parameter. `callBackTime:` "passes on" the value of its parameter to `NSLog()`, it doesn't pass it on to anything else. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to send a method to an object. You need two object , one is the object(receiver) the other is selector which describe what the message is. Maybe you need parameters if the selector has.

Here :

```
time_call = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
[Services get_time:self :@selector(callBackTime:)];

+(void) get_time:(id)delegate :(SEL)selector {
    NSLog(@"get time call"); 
}
```

delegate is the self(receiver) and selector is `@selector(callBackTime:)`. So in get_time it can send message to delegate like this:

```
[delegate performSelector:selector withObject:result] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your asking how to pass an object from the class Services maybe you can try something like this:

```
-(void)callBackTime:(NSString *)result{
    NSLog(@">> %@",result);
}

+(void) get_time:(id)delegate :(SEL)selector {
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:selector]){
        //pass the object here using the selector you have
        [delegate performSelector:selector withObject:@"theObject"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can pass perameter like that

This is what you are doing

```
 [Services get_time:self :@selector(callBackTime:)];
```

This is what you have to do for passing parameter

```
    [Services get_time:self :@selector(callBackTime:yourResultString)];
```